# Shuffle with cross_validation

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, cross-validation

I have a dataset like this:

```
[  5.        ,   2.        ,  15.        ,   0.25535303],
   [  5.        ,   3.        ,  15.        ,   6.72465845],
   [  5.        ,   4.        ,  15.        ,   5.62719504],
   [  5.        ,   5.        ,  15.        ,   5.61760597],
   [  5.        ,   6.        ,  15.        ,   4.9561533 ],
   [  6.        ,   2.        ,  15.        ,   0.2709665 ],
   [  6.        ,   3.        ,  15.        ,   6.07004364],
   [  6.        ,   4.        ,  15.        ,   5.62719504],
   [  6.        ,   5.        ,  15.        ,   5.54684885],
   [  6.        ,   6.        ,  15.        ,   5.32846201],
   [  2.        ,   2.        ,  20.        ,   3.79257349],
   [  2.        ,   3.        ,  20.        ,   4.00440964],
   [  2.        ,   4.        ,  20.        ,   4.37965706],
   [  2.        ,   5.        ,  20.        ,   3.92216922],
   [  2.        ,   6.        ,  20.        ,   3.41378368],
   [  3.        ,   2.        ,  20.        ,   0.13500398],
   [  3.        ,   3.        ,  20.        ,   4.38384781],
   [  3.        ,   4.        ,  20.        ,   5.17229688],
   [  3.        ,   5.        ,  20.        ,   5.00464056],
```

The third column values go from 15 to 35. I wanted to apply cross-validation but I suspected that the K-Folds would only include in each K block the same value in the third column, and it would affect negatively to my model.

Therefore, my solution is:

```
dataset_shuffle = shuffle(dataset)
X = dataset_shuffle["A", "B", "C"]
y = dataset_shuffle["D"]

result = cross_validate(estimator,X,y,scoring=scoretypes,cv=5,return_train_score=False)

r2 = result['test_r2'].mean()
mselist = -result['test_neg_mean_squared_error']
rmse = np.sqrt(mselist).mean()
```

Do you consider this a proper solution to my problem?
Is my solution the same as doing this?:

```
X = dataset["A", "B", "C"]
y = dataset["D"]
cv = KFold(n_splits=5, shuffle=True)
result = cross_validate(estimator,X,y,scoring=scoretypes,cv=cv,return_train_score=False)
```

Comment: Why exactly do you think that using `shuffle=True` is not enough?

Comment: I wasn't really sure, just wanted to clarify. I have seen some ways to apply Cross-validation like train_test_split or some Kaggle competitions where they use cross_validate multiple times and I was a bit confused. For a small dataset (120 samples) do you recommend any methodology to avoid overfitting? or the one that I posted would be enough? Thank you!